# Date Format in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursors

I am importing data from another sources, which has multiple columns but I am facing problem in date column like I have multiple format in this column like:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy
mmm-yyyy
```

Can you guide me how can accommodate these format during migrate data (using cursor to transfer data from temporary table to destination table).

How can i convert `mmm-yyyy` date format to `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Comment: You have different format in a single column? How do you know if 01/04/2011 means April 1 or January 4 ?

Comment: that's the problem

Comment: For dates like that there is no solution.

Comment: @Tony as stated in the question the column is a date column. Even if you don't know the difference,SQL server knows the difference.

Comment: @Stan - I understood the question to be concerning *importing* data in to a date field. If the OP already has the data in 'date' form there would be no need to ask about accommodating the different formats mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Xulfee - Can you clarify which data type is used by the source data for the dates? I'm assuming you are having to convert strings to a date or datetime type given they are displayed in different formats.

Comment: @Xulfee - are there any other columns on your data source that can be used to infer/identify the format of the date?  (Country/SystemID/..)

Answer (score 6):

There is **no way** to distinguish the meaning of 01/02/2011 and 02/01/2011 if you have this values mixed in the same column. It is that simple.

Comment: +1 The only time you will be able to tell the difference is when the value of the number in the month position is greater than 12 but that's not going to help in all the other cases.

Comment: That answer **assumes** that the only info you have is the string representing the date. *if* there is something else on the row which can infer the type of formatting used then **maybe** it can have some smarts...